# Undefined symbol: "_ZN7OpenANN3NetC1Ev"

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I decided to try to write an artificial neural network. I plan to use it in Java applications, but the library is written in C++.

With this in mind, I decided to try "razobrotsya JNI".

Could anybody help me solve the problem.
I'm trying to use the library `openANN` in Java, but upon compilation, I receieve the following error:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /home/user/workspace/opneANN_java_test/libfor_java_test.so: undefined symbol: _ZN7OpenANN3NetC1Ev
```

forJavaNativeAnn.cpp:

```
#include <OpenANN/OpenANN>
#include <OpenANN/io/Logger.h>
#include <OpenANN/io/DirectStorageDataSet.h>
#include <OpenANN/util/Random.h>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h>
#include "com_centreit_NativeAnn.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_centreit_NativeAnn_run(JNIEnv *env, jclass myclass) {
    const int d = 4;
    const int f = 4;
    const int n = 18;
    Eigen::MatrixXd x(n, d);
    Eigen::MatrixXd t(n, f);
    x <<
            2, 0, 0, 0,
            2, 0, 0, 1,
            2, 0, 1, 1,
            2, 0, 1, 2,
            2, 1, 0, 2,
            2, 1, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0,
            1, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 1, 1,
            1, 0, 1, 2,
            1, 1, 0, 2,
            1, 1, 0, 1,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1,
            0, 0, 1, 1,
            0, 0, 1, 2,
            0, 1, 0, 2,
            0, 1, 0, 1;
    t <<
            0, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 1, 0,
            1, 0, 0, 0,
            1, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1,
            0, 0, 0, 1,
            0, 0, 0, 1,
            0, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1,
            0, 0, 0, 1,
            0, 1, 0, 0,
            0, 1, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1;
    OpenANN::Net net;
    OpenANN::makeMLNN(net, OpenANN::LOGISTIC, OpenANN::LOGISTIC, d, f, 1, 1200);
    net.trainingSet(x, t);
    Eigen::VectorXd v(4);
    v << 2, 0, 0, 0;
    Eigen::VectorXd out = net(v);
    std::cout << out << std::endl;
}
```

`make` command in NetBeans IDE:

```
g++ -m64   -c -O2 -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/include -std=c++98 -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF "build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/forJavaNativeAnn.o.d" -o build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/forJavaNativeAnn.o forJavaNativeAnn.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86
g++ -m64    -o dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/libfor_java_test.so build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/forJavaNativeAnn.o  -shared -fPIC
```

My Java code:

```
public class NativeAnn {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("for_java_test");
    }
    native public static void run();
}
```

Comment: Append `-lopenann` to the link line. Does that make it work?

Comment: g++ -m64 -Wl,-rpath, -I/usr/local/include/OpenANN -I/usr/local/include/alglib -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/eigen3 -L/usr/local/lib -lopenann -lgomp    -o dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/libfor_java_test.so build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/forJavaNativeAnn.o  -shared -fPIC
 don't work((

Comment: Put the `-l` flags at the end of the link line, or you'll have funny effects with static libraries.